# Count occurrences where

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT serial, model, owner, COUNT(*) AS occurrences 
FROM cars
GROUP BY serial WHERE owner = 'Mike'
ORDER BY occurrences DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

How would one modify this query to actually work? I want to count the 5 most commons serial numbers owned by Mike and display the Model - Owner - Amount of serials data on site.

Comment: `GROUP BY serial WHERE owner = 'Mike'` to `WHERE owner = 'Mike' GROUP BY serial`

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the order of WHERE clause and GROUP BY.

try this:

```
  SELECT serial, model, owner, COUNT(*) AS occurrences 
  FROM cars
  WHERE owner = 'Mike'
  GROUP BY serial 
  ORDER BY occurrences DESC 
  LIMIT 5
```